# VB.NET ClickOnce Deployment: What Files Are Required?

Tags: vb.net, deployment, clickonce

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 with VB.NET. I have created and published my application. This creates "setup.exe" and "windowsapplication.application" files together with a folder called "Application Files" that in turn contains another folder with some DLLs in it. All these files/folders are created in a folder called "publish".

My question is this: What files/folders do I actually need to send to an end user (CD-ROM installation) so that they can install my program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all files in the publish folder. But check the Application files, it contains the current and all previous builds in seperate folders.